# Unnaturally increasing the width of a div :)

Tags: css

let's say I have a div with right-aligned text and a fixed with:

```
div{
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

is it ok if I increase the width of this div to `35px` trough padding, to move the text away from the edge and avoid adding another element inside of it?

```
div{
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I mean would any browsers behave weirdly about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result would be exacly what you said: a div of total width 35px. It seems to me you understand what you are doing, but there is never a substitute for actually testing in all your target browsers.

While this small piece of CSS looks innocent, it can change the elements around them in a way you didn't expect.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer in Quirks Mode would have a problem with it due to it's [box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).
If this is a problem, I would use a nested div that uses margins instead.
Your other option could be including an IE specific CSS file.

Comment: Your quoted bug is no longer relevant. Quote: `"Internet Explorer 6 and newer are not affected in their standards-compliant mode, but for compatibility reasons, the bug is still present when a page is rendered in "quirks mode"."` - no modern websites are using Quirks Mode.

Comment: No modern websites use quirks mode, but depending on how the page is set up, it could put IE into quirks mode. Just providing the information for potential problems.

Comment: True, but you probably should have mentioned that in your answer. If you manage to *accidentally* create a website that's in Quirks Mode in IE, you've got bigger problems than `5px` of missing padding.

Answer (score 2):

No It'll be ok, in every major browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area that we are getting a lot more control over with css3.  Have a look at
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html.